# aborting previous steps in curl, xargs pipe when head finishes

Tags: zsh, pipe, curl, head

I'm trying to download a bunch of web pages, and once I've downloaded N lines of html, I want the whole thing to stop. But instead, the previous steps in the pipe just keep going. An example to see the problem:

```
for i in /accessories /aches-pains /allergy-hayfever /baby-child /beauty-skincare; do echo $i; sleep 2; done | \
while read -r line; do curl "https://www.medino.com$line"; done \
 | head -n 2
```

Now, I want this to make a single request, then abort.

But what happens instead is this:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
100  4412    0  4412    0     0  12788      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 12751
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 2358)
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  2358    0  2358    0     0   3772      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  3766
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 2358)

( ^ repeats 4 times)
```

Why doesn't the script abort immediately, and instead keeps going? I'm not a super pro on pipes so feel like I'm missing something fundamental here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second part of your pipeline is `while read -r line; do curl ...$line; done`. When this runs:

1. on first iteration shell reads the first value into line, and runs curl; curl (fetches and) outputs the webpage, of which `head -n2` extracts the first two lines and exits, closing the pipe between the second and third parts. It appears in your example curl writes this output as at least two blocks, so it gets an error on the second write and fails i.e. exits with nonzero status.
2. shell does not terminate most command sequences (including a compound command) when one command fails, because shells are frequently used interactively, and it would be very inconvenient to have your shell die forcing you to re-login and start over every time you make any mistake running any program.
3. thus the shell reads the second value into line and runs the second curl, which immediately fails because the pipe is closed, but again the shell continues and reads the third line and runs the third curl, etc until end of input causes `read` to fail; since `read` is in the list-1 part of `while`, its failure causes the loop to terminate.

You can explicitly test if curl failed (and then terminate) with:

```
generate_values | while read -n line && curl ...$line; do :; done | head -n2
```

or you can set a shell option so it *does* terminate on failure:

```
generate_values | { set -e; while read -n line; do curl ...$line; done } | head -n2
```

Note for both methods it may run *one* over, because curl reports an error only on a write *after* the pipe is closed, i.e. after the last block. If your output limit (`head -n$n`) is exhausted during the last block of output from curl #2, that curl will exit 'success' and the shell will start curl #3 which will fail on its first (or only) write.